# HTML5 Video formats

Tags: html, html5-video

I need to add a video to a website using HTML5 video tags.
What format will the video need to be in to work cross browser desktop and mobile.

There are lots of posts on stackoverflow, but most seem to be from a few years ago. is there a more up to date list ?

Looking at this list https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats would it be safe to assume that WebM,  Ogg and MP4 will be enough ?

thanks.

Comment: Instead of duplicating the question, which is still the same, you should ensure that the existing answers are up to date. Either leave a comment if you think an answer is outdated, do your own research to update answers, or put a bounty on the question to invite updated answers. If you can point out a particularly good duplicate I might even be willing to spend the points for you on the bounty.

Comment: Having said that, since browser support is changing over time, such a time-sensitive topic may not be a good fit for SO in the first place, precisely because information ages.

Answer (score 0):

Video tag only supports three formats:

> In HTML5, there are 3 supported video formats: MP4, WebM, and Ogg.

You can find an updated guide with all the attributes available in W3Schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp